# How to create a MS Word document using SSIS package?

Tags: ssis

Using Script Task, I have written a code to create a folder and create a MS Word document inside the newly created folder. It is working on the local machine but it is not working on the server where the package is deployed to. The folder is created successfully, but the Word document file is not created. For Word document creation, I had to refer another DLL where I had included an additional namespace `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`. Is there anything else to do before deployment ?

Comment: Do you have ms office installed on the server where the word document is being created?

Comment: or is there any dll file of MSWord to be included in the production server ? or assembly file ? if so, how is it to be done ? because this is working in local machine. And one thing is that the local machine is having MSOffice 2007 while the production server where I am unable to create word document file, is having MSOffice 2003.

Comment: That could be it since you are using the MS.Word.Interop dll version 12.0.0.0 to create 2007 word documents on your local box which is being deployed in your pkg to the server where office 2003 lives.

Comment: yes. I have used the same version 12.0.0. So whats the dll version to create 2003 word or both 2003 and 2007 word ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon rfonn's comments, your choices are as follows:

1. Install Word 2007 on the server.
2. Re-do your package on a dev box with Word 2003 installed and deploy to your server.
3. Use some other tool to generate the Word Document.

SSIS is generally used for movement of data, so while it is possible to do what you are doing, it is likely not the best tool for the job.  If you are capable of writing code in a script task to do what you want in SSIS, it is possible to write a program (VB or C# or any other tool you choose) to do the same thing without SSIS being wrapped around it. My money is on option #3 being your best choice.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you missed installing the Office PIA.

After installing the relevent PIA according to your Office version, add a reference to  `microsoft.office.interop.word` (.NET) file in your project (ssis script in VS).